# is there any way to change the SharePoint APP permission?

Tags: sharepoint-addin

I add APP to my site that have a manage permission, this app can do more with full permission. is there any way to change the permission for this App?

Answer (score 1):

If the app is something you have built, then you can recompile a new version of the app, change the requested permissions in the manifest and increment the version.

When you deploy the update for the app, the user will be asked to trust the app again with the new permissions.

Comment: of course is is not something I built (if so, as I give it a manage permission I can give it a full permission), anyway, I add it form the App store